# app.yaml for java google endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to convert java web.xml to app.yaml for google endpoints so I can use git to deploy instead of maven.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>rest1.Greetings</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Tried

```
application: test
version: 0
runtime: java
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  name: SystemServiceServlet
  servlet: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
  init_params:
   services: rest1.Greetings
   load-on-startup: 1

static_files:
- include: /*
  secure: always
  login: admin
# http_headers:
#  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://

welcome_files:
- index.html

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

But when I upload it using git it fails to deploy my endpoint. 
https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/tree/master/appengine/rs is the current working tree that works using maven appengine update.

PS I think https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml has not been updated? And api_version:1 give me a wrong api version?